# Restringir que dos o más usuarios consulten la misma tabla al mismo tiempo MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Mi problema es que tengo un programa abierto en varios pc en la empresa donde trabajo y he visto que si dos personas hacen un pedido al mismo tiempo, ambos programas hacen la consulta a la vez y les devuelve a las dos el pedido 5 (fusionando los datos de los dos pedidos que tomaron por separado) y lo que necesito es que a uno de los dos, le salga el pedido 5 con sus datos y al otro el 6 con los suyos.

Básicamente sería como poner al usuario 2 en lista de espera para consultar la tabla mientras el primero termina la suya, así no la harían a la vez o bloquear la tabla mientras un usuario hace consultas en ella y desbloquearla cuando acabe para que el otro usuario que está en espera haga su consulta.

El programa está en Java con una base de datos MySQL.

Cualquier ayuda la agradecería muchísimo.

PD: He leído sobre lock table y unlock table pero no se si esto deja al usuario en espera o cancela su consulta

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser que estás generando el ID del pedido manualmente, y para cuando el proceso ha concluido, ya hay otro pedido con el mismo número. Intenta usar campos *autoincrement* para definir el ID en el momento de crear el pedido.

Otra solución es crear el pedido vacío primero de forma que puedas reservar el número de la secuencia del pedido y luego actualizas la entrada.

Es todo lo que puedo decirte sin ver tu código. Estas colisiones pueden evitarse sin bloquear la tabla. Puede que la clave esté en reservar la entrada y luego actualizar el pedido.

Comment: El ID se genera con Autoincrement. Por eso me parece raro que esto suceda. Cuando esté en mi casa pego el fragmento de codigo que ejecuto que es muy sencillo. Gracias por el interes MightyMouse

Comment: Yo sugiero utilizar transacciones en los insert a tu bd, ajustando el nivel de aislamiento más adecuado a tu necesidad.

Comment: Como sería un ejemplo??